# Can I use Inheritance of PostgreSQL for getting a particular set of columns in many tables in one database?

Tags: database, postgresql, inheritance, rdbms

In Postgresql 10 , I want to have same set of columns for audit purpose in all transactional tables of a particular database with same Foreign Key Constraints.

I am thinking of creating a master table with the set of 4 columns:

```
createdBy  createdOn  updatedBy  updatedOn
```

Then inherit all transactional tables from this master table.

Is this the right approach and is inheritance suited for this? When it comes to storage of data, how it works behind the scenes when I insert records into the derived/child tables. What happens when data is deleted from child tables. Can I lock my master table so that no one accidentally deletes any records from master table ?

Answer (score 1):

I see no problem with that approach but it works differently from your description.

I will use the following tables for illustration:

```
CREATE TABLE MasterAudit (
    createdBy TEXT                     DEFAULT current_user,
    createdOn TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT current_timestamp,
    updatedBy TEXT                     DEFAULT current_user,
    updatedOn TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT current_timestamp
);
CREATE TABLE SlaveAudit (
    Val Text
) INHERITS(MasterAudit);
```

This definition allows to skip columns when inserting / use the `default` keyword for inserts and updates.

---

1. **What does `SELECT` do** (visible when using `EXPLAIN`)**?**
   Behind the scene, data inserted into `SlaveAudit` is stored into `SlaveAudit`; selecting from `MasterAudit` works with `UNION` of tables, including `MasterAudit` itself (it is valid to insert data into the parent table, although it would not make much sense in this very case).

   - `SELECT * FROM SlaveAudit` reads data from `SlaveAudit`. The additional column `Val` from `SlaveAudit` is returned.
   - `SELECT * FROM MasterAudit` reads data from `MasterAudit UNION SlaveAudit`. The additional column `Val` is not returned.
   - `SELECT * FROM ONLY MasterAudit` reads data from `MasterAudit` only.
   - Illustration aside, the correct way to select from `MasterAudit` is by using the pseudo-column `tableoid` in order to determine where each record comes from.

Be careful though, it can be very long to get if all your tables inherit from `MasterAudit`

```
SELECT relname, MasterAudit.*
FROM MasterAudit
JOIN pg_class ON MasterAudit.tableoid = pg_class.oid
```

2. **Let's insert stuff.**
   `INSERT INTO SlaveAudit(Val) VALUES ('Some value');`
   What query will result in deleting it?

   - `DELETE FROM SlaveAudit` will remove that record (obviously).
   - `DELETE FROM MasterAudit` will remove the record too. Oops! that is not what we want.
   - `TRUNCATE TABLE SlaveAudit` and `TRUNCATE Table MasterAudit` will have the same result as the 2 `DELETE`.
3. **Time to manage access.**
   IMHO, no commands apart from `SELECT` should ever be granted on `MasterAudit`.

   - Creating a table that inherits `MasterAudit` can only be done by its owner. You may want to change the tables' owner.
     `ALTER TABLE MasterAudit OWNER TO ...`
   - Almost all the privileges must be revoked. It includes the table owner (but please note the super user will not be affected). `SELECT` on `MasterAudit` may be granted to everyone if you want.
     `REVOKE ALL ON MasterAudit FROM public, ...`
     `GRANT SELECT ON MasterAudit TO public`
   - Check the access by ensuring the following queries fail:
     `INSERT INTO MasterAudit VALUES(default, default, default, default)`
     `DELETE FROM MasterAudit`

Comment: So, what i understand from your response is that it is not advised to use this MasterAudit if i am planning to inherit the 4 columns in some 50 transaction tables i have. And the reason for this is that there will be lag or delays in accessing the data ?

Comment: No, I have said I saw no problems with the approach (= my first sentence). If by "lags and delays", you are referring to the last sentence I wrote in point #1, then it only applies when you select from `MasterAudit` directly. It will not impact any of the other tables. Something being fine does not mean it needs no care at all :)

Comment: Thanks  for your time and valuable inputs @lau